Looking for a Apple laptop for development
I am using Delphi for development.  To write apps for iPhone, I need a Apple laptop.  Its an Apple requirement, I guess to get licence fees for xcode.  Its only for debugging and deploying.
I am looking for

An Apple laptop
Not too bulky
Not too old
About $1000 (AUD) or less
I don't care about the size of the screen

